# Include rgl interactive plot in .Rnw (pdf output)

Tags: r, knitr, rgl, rnw

### Description of Problem

I'd like to include an interactive (rotating) rgl 3-d scatterplot in a .pdf knitted from a .Rnw file.  I know there is a hook for including `rgl` but maybe this is for html output only.  I can't seem to include the plot so that it rotates.  Here is a minimal example.  The plot appears but there are lines rather than points and no rotation available.

### Question(s)

1. Is including the interactive rgl in a pdf possible?
2. If so...How can I do this with knitr?; what am I doing incorrectly?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(rgl) 
knit_hooks$set(rgl = hook_rgl)
@

<<fancy-rgl, rgl=TRUE>>=
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
# open3d()
plot3d(x, y, z, col = 'black')
@


\end{document}
```

### What I see in pdf:

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that PDF files can only render static content.

Comment: I hope this is not true.  You can include animations.  The hooks example uses this very example: http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/ This also indicated interactive rgl could happen but this doesn't render as dynamic either: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/092-latex-rgl.Rnw

Comment: This indicates it's just a single image: `if we want to insert 3D snapshots produced in rgl` from http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/

Comment: I'm not sure how the linked `knitr` examples are supposed to work, but when I tried them they did not generate an interactive plot in the PDF document. I'm pretty sure this is just a limitation of the PDF format in general, not necessarily specific to `knitr` or `rgl`. [This thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Creating-interactive-3D-graphs-for-embedding-in-pdf-not-possible-in-R-td4634174.html) is somewhat relevant to your question.

Comment: Only Adobe PDF Reader supports animations. The animation was created by the LaTeX package animate. I remember there are LaTeX packages that support interactive 3D plots, but I don't know if rgl can be connected with these packages.

Comment: @Whomever downvoted you must be either a troll, ignorant of the help center guide (I'll post here for your reading convenience: http://stackoverflow.com/help), or you simply made an error.  If you really feel the question is that poorly formatted or out of scope please post an explanatory comment so that I may improve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but just barely. You need to install Asymptote, and use `rgl::writeASY()` to write a program for it.  Then include that program in your document, run LaTeX, then Asymptote, then LaTeX again.

There are examples of including Asymptote in LaTeX here:  http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/LaTeX-usage.html#LaTeX-usage.

The results are kind of disappointing.

My advice would be to abandon PDF.  HTML5 is a much better target for output; `rgl` does quite a good job (using `rglwidget()`) producing output for web pages.  It's really unlikely that any effort will be put into improving PDF output, whereas fixing the remaining gaps in HTML support are a priority.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree on the pdf.  It's for a dissertation where I needed extreme control over formatting and much of the cool rmarkdown stuff we have now was new or missing when I started it 2 years ago.

Comment: @TylerRinker You can insert a static screenshot in the PDF, and link to the interactive HTML version that you deploy somewhere like Github pages or Dropbox.

Comment: It would be very helpful if someone included an example of this as another answer.